# Why can't I change the valueStack of Struts2?

Tags: java, json, struts2, interceptor, valuestack

I do some operation of Struts2's value stack in an interceptor,code like this:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation actionInvocation) throws Exception {
    String invokeRes = actionInvocation.invoke();
    ValueStack valueStack = actionInvocation.getStack();

    List<Object> shouldCheckFieldValues = Lists.newArrayList();

    List<String> keywords = Lists.newArrayList("哈哈", "头部", "测试");
    RegexKeywordFilter filter = new RegexKeywordFilter();
    filter.add(keywords);
    filter.compile();

    final ReplaceStrategy highLightStrategy = new ReplaceStrategy() {
        @Override
        public String replaceWith(String keyword) {
            return "<span style='background-color:red;'>" + keyword + "</span>";
        }
    };

    Object respObj = valueStack.findValue("resp");

    if (respObj instanceof JoyPageWebDTO) {
        JoyPageWebDTO pageWebDTO = (JoyPageWebDTO) respObj;
        List<?> recordsList = pageWebDTO.getRecords();
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(recordsList)) {
            for (Object audit : recordsList) {
                for (Field field : audit.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (field.isAnnotationPresent(AICheck.class)) {
                        boolean fieldIsAccess = field.isAccessible();
                        if (!fieldIsAccess) field.setAccessible(true);

                        Object fieldValue = field.get(audit);
                        if (fieldValue instanceof String && filter.hasKeywords((String) fieldValue)) {
                            String replacedStr = filter.replace((String) fieldValue, highLightStrategy);
                            field.set(audit, replacedStr);
                        }
                        if (!fieldIsAccess) field.setAccessible(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return invokeRes;
}
```

The valuestack before intercept is :

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHqqD.png]

The valuestack after intercept is:

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ths7m.png]

It's seamed the valuestack has changed.However,the really return result is:

```
{
"pageIndex": 0,
"pageSize": 30,
"recordCount": 0,
"records": [
 {
  "auditContent": "",
  "auditID": 354,
  "auditStatus": 3,
  "bizStatus": 1,
  "bodyPart": "2",
  "categoryID": 141,
  "city": "上海",
  "desc": "22",
  "duration": 2,
  "forbidden": "2",
  "indications": "2",
  "name": "头部按摩很爽很爽"
 }
]
}
```

I use xml config,code like this:

```
<package name="ajax" namespace="/ajax" extends="json-default">
    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="aiCheck"
                     class="com.dianping.joy.admin.web.interceptor.AICheckInterceptor">
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor-stack name="defaultInterceptorStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="aiCheck" />
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>
    <default-interceptor-ref name="defaultInterceptorStack"/>

    <action name="searchJoySpu" class="com.action.SpuSearchAction">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">resp</param>
        </result>
    </action>
 </package>
```

The return result is not changed. Why and how can I change this get the changed result?

Comment: How do you return a result?

Comment: I use struts xml config. I edit the question,and add the return result way in to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the object after it has been serialized, so JSON contains the old value.

You can use `PreResultListener` in the interceptor to handle data before `json` result is executed.

> **[PreResultListener](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/pre-result-listener.html)**
>
> A `PreResultListener` can affect an action invocation between the
> interceptor/action phase and the result phase. Typical uses include
> switching to a different `Result` or somehow modifying the `Result` or
> `Action` objects **before** the `Result` executes.
>
> ```java
> public class MyInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {
>    ...
>     public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
>        invocation.addPreResultListener(new PreResultListener() {
>             public void beforeResult(ActionInvocation invocation, 
>                                      String resultCode) {
>                 // perform operation necessary before Result execution
>             }
>        });
>     }
>    ...
> }
> ```

Comment: My purpose is to handle the data value after invoke.If `actionInvocation.invoke()` moved to the end of the method,I cannot get the `Object respObj = valueStack.findValue("resp")`.Only when after `actionInvocation.invoke()`,the `respObj` is not null.

Comment: @yonney.yang Then use `PreResultListener`.

Comment: Thank you very much.I solved this problem with your suggestion.